# How to repeat multiple animations indefinitely in Android

Tags: android, animation

I have the following code.

```
Iterator imagesIterator = mImages.iterator();
while (arrowsIterator.hasNext()) {
   ImageView image = (ImageView) imagesIterator.next();

   TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(
        TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
        TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
        TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f,
        TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f
   );

   anim.setDuration(10000);
   anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
   anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
   image.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

The idea is that I want a set all images to "fall" down from the top of the screen and repeat that infinitely (from top to bottom).

The problem I'm having now is that it seems it's waiting until all images are done with their animation to repeat them all at once again.

I don't want that, I want them to repeat as soon as each one of those images reach the bottom so it looks like an infinite cascade loop of images falling down from the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you naively assume that as soon as `image.startAnimation(anim)` is reached the animation is started.

In fact your loop terminates, then a message is being posted on main Looper, and then your animations are being started. And they will run simultaneously, because you haven't specified otherwise.

What you can do, is to give an initial delay to each animation in your loop.

```
Iterator imagesIterator = mImages.iterator();
long offset = 0;
while (arrowsIterator.hasNext()) {
    ImageView image = (ImageView) imagesIterator.next();

    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f
    );

    anim.setDuration(10000);
    anim.setStartOffset(offset);
    offset += 100; // each animation will be delayed by 100ms from the previous
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    image.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Comment: Yeah actually I want them to start all at once. But they are also ending all at once. What I found out is that what is wrongly configured are the translation offsets. If I set from -1.0f to 1.0f and give it a delay as you wrote I kind of get the desired behavior, not entirely, as In the perferct world what I would want the images to start from the top of the screen again whenever they are totally off the screen from the bottom. This is what I meant with an infinite loop simulating a cascade.

Comment: For that cascading effect you have to set different durations and different offsets for all animations.